# Getting innerHTML of an element by clicking another element that comes after it

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a table with a few rows each tr has 3 td's that each has a class; "td1", "td2" and "td3", `td3` has a `<span>` inside it which acts as a link like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="td1">This is td number 1 in row 1</td>
    <td class="td2">This is td number 2 in row 1</td>
    <td class="td3">This is td number 3 in row 1<span class="clickMeLink">Click me</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="td1">This is td number 1 in row 2</td>
    <td class="td2">This is td number 2 in row 2</td>
    <td class="td3">This is td number 3 in row 2<span class="clickMeLink">Click me</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>

    $('.clickMeLink').on('click', function () {

    });
```

Is there a way for me to get the innerHTML of `td2` that is beofore the clicked `<span>`.
So if I click the `<span>` in row 1 I would get the innerHTML of the `td2` in row 1. I would like to store the resulting innerHTML in a variable that I can use in another function.

I hope this made sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/JPWEd/)</kbd>

```
$('.clickMeLink').click(function () {
    var txt = $(this).parent().prev().html();
//                      ^ parent of current element and than gets it's previous td
    alert(txt);
});
```

[this keyword](https://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/)

[.prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)

[.parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)

Comment: Great, that targets the right thing!
But can I use this variable in another function?

Comment: @user3088863 yes you can what you want ??

Comment: @user3088863 - You would have to make the variable `txt` have a higher scope. You can do this by defining the variable outside of `$('.clickMeLink').click()`, but setting the value inside of that function.

Comment: @user3088863 Declare `var txt` outside the click function. Than assign value without using `var` keyword `txt = $(this).parent().prev().html();`

Comment: Ah thank you!! That was it - declaring outside and not using var inside!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.clickMeLink').on('click', function(){
    $yourtd = $(this).parents('tr').find('.td2');
    console.log($yourtd);
})
```